# MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem not working

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I'm working with Android on a Media Player app, when creating a playlist in the database and then try to modify it, like removing songs from the playlist or moving song to other position(the app has a reordering feature, drag and drop), it simply doesn't work. I'm using these two codes for removing and reordering:

```
public boolean movePlaylistSong(int playlistId, int from, int to){
    try{
        return MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem(context.getContentResolver(), playlistId, from, to);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean removeFromPlaylist(int playlistId, int audioId) {
    try{
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);
        return resolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID +"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(audioId)}) != 0;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

They both return true that it was successful but when reloading the playlist from the database(The external content uri of the playlists) again it returns the original one with NO CHANGES applied. It returns success result but it actually didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem does not work for me also! Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 1):

Calling moveItem will change the PLAY_ORDER value, but you need to sort by the PLAY_ORDER on your cursor to see the change.  Otherwise the cursor will sort by _ID, which doesn't get edited.

```
Uri uriPlaylistTracks = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistID);
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER;
cursor = resolver.query(uriPlaylistTracks, STAR, null, null, sortOrder);
```

To change the PLAY_ORDER, I did this:

```
//get the PLAY_ORDER values for song
cursor.moveToPosition(fromPosition);
int from = (int) cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER));
cursor.moveToPosition(toPosition); //position in list
int to = (int) cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER));
//update the PLAY_ORDER values using moveItem
boolean result = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem(resolver,
                playlistID, from, to);
//get new cursor with the updated PLAY_ORDERs
cursor = resolver.query(uriPlaylistTracks, STAR, null, null, sortOrder);
//change the cursor for a listview adapter
adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I think your answer is helpful, about the sortOrder. But method MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem does not work, need to use the resolver.update method instead.

Comment: The moveItem method has worked on the devices I've tested so far --  I added some code to the answer for how I use the moveItem command.  It's important to use the PLAY_ORDER values in it.

Comment: This did not work for me. What did is 'MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem(resolver, playlistID, fromPosition, toPosition);' So I guess you should not use the Play_Order values in moveItem().

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with same issue. Behaves as successful but no change. I did note however that your playlistid is of type int yet the documentation states long.

```
public static final boolean  moveItem (ContentResolver res, long playlistId, int from, int to)
```

I also found this answer on the forum
[Alternative to MediaStore.Playlists.Members.moveItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252878/alternative-to-mediastore-playlists-members-moveitem)

I found that it does move the PLAY_ORDER but not the AUDIO_ID.